# Laravel use reference from SQL

Tags: sql, laravel

I use the SQL command SELECT AS to retrieve some calculated results from my query in Laravel 5.1
How can i later in this query use my new referces to calculate something?
I want to do something like this to get the average rating.

```
SELECT (rating_food + rating_service + rating_decor)/3 as rating_total
```

.

```
$query->leftJoin('reviews', 'restaurant_id', '=', 'restaurants.id');
$query->addSelect([
    'restaurants.*',
    DB::raw('avg(reviews.rating_food) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_food'),
    DB::raw('avg(reviews.rating_service) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_service'),
    DB::raw('avg(reviews.rating_decor) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_decor')
]);
```

(this is taken from a scope.)

Comment: Can't you just do `$query->selectRaw('(rating_food + rating_service + rating_decor) / 3 AS rating_total')` after those existing selects, or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: rating_food, rating_service and rating_decor are references i select. So i cant use your solution.

Comment: Wow, didn't realise you couldn't refer to other select columns in a later select column.

Comment: I dunno if it's any more efficient but you might want to create a view for these restaurant ratings. I hear views aren't amazing, performance-wise, but maybe they're better than this temporary-table subquery thing you've ended up with?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.
Add it as a FROM query.

```
$query->from(DB::raw('
(
    SELECT
    avg(reviews.rating_food) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_food,
    avg(reviews.rating_service) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_service,
    avg(reviews.rating_decor) * (- 1 / (0.33 * count(reviews.id) + 1) + 1) + 5 * 1 / (count(reviews.id) + 1 ) as rating_decor
    FROM restaurants
    JOIN reviews ON reviews.restaurant_id = restaurants.id
)
as rating, restaurants
'));
```